# 301 redirect when new page has same url structure

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Trying to set up a redirect so
 mysite.com/x/services directs to mysite.com/x/services/specific.

Tried it like this
`Redirect 301 /x/services http://www.mysite.com/x/services/specific`

but what I end up with is 
`http://www.mysite.com/x/services/specific/specific/specific/specific/specific/specific/specific`
into eternity.

I'm figuring this is because `/x/services/` is still in there.

I've read a bit about redirects to new domains, new structures -- but how do you get around the loop?

Many thanks,

-m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your Redirect line with this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/x/services/?$ http://www.mysite.com/x/services/specific
```